# VB.NET - Application has encountered a user-defined breakpoint

Tags: vb.net

I'm not that up on VB.NET, the application I'm working on was not written by myself.
It works fine through the IDE but once I run it from the exe it gives me the above error.

Any clues?

This is really hacking me off!

Comment: Is it compiled in Release mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Afaik, the only way this could occur if you are compiling under debugging settings. You *should* be able to fix it by doing the following:

1. Right-click your solution on the
   solution explorer.
2. Select configuration properties.
3. At the top of the dialog box there should be a
   combobox, which will most likely say
   "Active(Debug)".
4. Click on the dropdown and select release.
5. Ok out of everything.
6. Build > Rebuild Solution.

Source: [p2p.wrox.com](http://p2p.wrox.com/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=7712)

Answer (score 5):

The only user defined break point that I can think of is

```
Debugger.Break()
```

So, I would suspect that the .exe is compiled in debug mode.  I would recommend [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/index.htm) to look at the code and find out for sure whether or not there is a Debugger.Break() somewhere in there.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the exe file was compiled using the "Debug" setting. Try changing the Build setting to Release and do a full build (rebuild) of the project. Then try to run the executable file. It should then run normally.

The reason you see that error is because when you normally compile and run applications in Visual Studio, it compiles a Debug build of the executable. The different between a debug build and a release build is that the debug build has additional information added to it, by the compiler, so it can be debugged properly.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking for `stop` in your code.  That is what generated this error for me.